# Android intent to view an item using Amazon app on device rather than browser

Tags: android, android-intent, amazon-appstore

In my Android app, I have a button with the background image of an Amazon.com product (let's say a shirt or something), and when clicked I would like it to open in the Amazon app (com.amazon.mShop.android) if is already installed rather than in the browser, and in the browser if the app is not installed.

I have been able to find how to add a deep link to a specific Amazon client app, but not how to link to a specific item that would open with open with the Amazon app.

Currently, my click listener opens in a browser by doing the following:

```
b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlOfItemOnAmazonSite));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Amazon developer's home page is probably the best place for this answer. This may be a good start: https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs/deeplink#Link%20Configuration. Here they explain how to construct the `Uri` you'll need to use to set the Intent data.

Of course, you may want to be careful and wrap `startActivity` in a try/catch in case Amazon isn't installed and it throws an [`ActivityNotFoundException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html)

Comment: That's what I found, but I'm pretty sure that is how to search the Amazon Appstore or link to a specific app, correct? So in their example, http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?asin=B004FRX0MY links directly to the MP3 app to purchase it. Rather, I want to set the intent data to pass the info for the shirt to the Amazon shopping app that is separate from the Appstore.

Comment: Yes that's for the Appstore. Well, you could also use Intent.setPackage() to set it to "com.amazon.mShop.android", but then you still have to be careful that the package has some IntentFilter that could handle your Intent,

Comment: According to this link: it's not just other apps that use the ASIN ids. https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/mobile-associates/docs/direct-linking-implementation#Direct%20to%20Amazon%20Product%20Detail%20Page. For example, using amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?asin=B008GGCAVM takes you to buy a Kindle Fire.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I have to sign up for an Amazon Mobile Assosciates API in order to integrate it.

Comment: Hi Phillip. I was wondering if you found the answer to this question as I am in the same boat. I'd like to launch the amazon shopping app and land on a specific product page.

Comment: Here's the updated link: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-deep-linking-to-the-amazon-client.html#link-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following:

```
b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       Uri uri=Uri.parse(productUrl);
       Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
})
```

//Note extract url of product store in var productUrl(or any other var) and //parse it.